# Got error while deploy rails code on server using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I am getting below `error` when tried to deploy using `capistrano`

```
Error: RVM was unable to use 'ruby-2.0.0-p353'
command finished in 841ms


** [deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::CommandError, failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-2.0.0-p353' -c 'rm -rf /home/demo/demoser/releases/20151019122017; true'" on xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Any one have a `solution`.

Thanks

Comment: what doe `rvm list` cmd return on your server.

Comment: rvm rubies   # No rvm rubies installed yet. means I have to install ruby on server?

Comment: But why rvm required on server. I have only one project on server. Without it how can i deploy on it? any idea?

Comment: Do you have proper configuration in `deploy.rb` for `rvm`?

Comment: I think..because its existing project of client so may be already did proper..

Comment: Check if server has ruby already? check different ruby version managers https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/ruby_version_management

Comment: ye ruby installed perfectly...